# iPhone: Avoid JavaScript Redirect

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Using the 2nd solution here: [Call Objective C method from JavaScript with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275093/call-objective-c-method-from-javascript-with-parameter), I have added the following line to some of my JavaScript code in order to pass some information back into Objective-C:

```
location.href = 'myApp://index=10';
```

The problem is, when I do this, the rest of the JavaScript on the page (after the location.href=... line) does not execute, and the browser is redirected to a blank page.  Is there any way to execute that line without having the browser go to a blank page in order to do so?

I appreciate any help, please let me know if I can clarify at all.  Thank you.

EDIT:
Objective-C code:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *url = [request URL] ;
    NSString *url2 = [[request URL] absoluteString];


    static NSString *urlPrefix = @"myApp://";
    if ([url2 hasPrefix:urlPrefix]) {
        NSString *paramsString = [url2 substringFromIndex:[urlPrefix length]];
        NSArray *paramsArray = [paramsString componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
        int paramsAmount = [paramsArray count];

        for (int i = 0; i < paramsAmount; i++) {
            NSArray *keyValuePair = [[paramsArray objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
            NSString *key = [keyValuePair objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *value = nil;
            if ([keyValuePair count] > 1) {
                value = [keyValuePair objectAtIndex:1];
            }

            if (key && [key length] > 0) {
                if (value && [value length] > 0) {
                    if ([key isEqualToString:@"index"]) {
                        NSLog(@"Works");
                        exit;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return NO;
    }


    if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"] || [[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"https"]) {
            return YES; 
    }

    else {
       return [ super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType ];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting a `href` value of the `location` object will always immediately result in a JavaScript redirect. That is, in fact, the main purpose of allowing the object to be writable.

If you're looking to update a URL fragment without a redirect or refresh try using the `location.hash` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately, when I try this, ``'myApp://index=10';`` doesn't even seem to get dealt with in AppDelegate.m.

Answer (score -1):

Attempt 1: Did you try setting `window.location` instead of `location.href`?

Attempt 2: Did you return NO in order to cancel the request on the Objective-C method?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, though unfortunately the problem persists.

Comment: I believe I did return NO, but I've added my code to my initial post in case maybe I'm doing it incorrectly?  Thanks.

Comment: Try not doing it that complicated at first. Just check whether or not the scheme matches yours: if so, return NO and log something; if not, return YES.

Comment: Well, it does get the data correctly, so I know it's getting the information from the redirect, yet even though I return NO, it still seems to redirect.

Comment: For some reason, it seems like it's still redirecting even when I return no?