# Objective-C calls from Javascript

Tags: javascript, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm trying to write some bridge between Javascript, which is called from UIWebView, and Objective-C calls. I find a lot of quiestions like that, and all of them saying that I should catch Javascript calls in

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

ok, it's easy (and only?) way to do this, so I'm looking to that direction.

All answers  to these quiestions say "parse url from webView and then with help of if-else send a message to Objective-C class". I have more than 10 functions in Javascript, so I don't want to parse them manually (these functions will have arrays of js objects as parameters and so on).

So the question is: are there any light libraries or opensource projects to convert/unconvert obj-C selectors and parameters into/from strings? (I am not so familiar with Javascript, but I think that do the same thing in much easy than in obj-C, so the main question is about obj-C)

PS I've found QuickConnectOC library, but I'm not sure if I can use it
PPS I think it is not difficult to write my own parser... but I don't want to reinvent wheel

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275093/call-objective-c-method-from-javascript-with-parameter

Comment: and if I have function like this: addSomething(a, b, [{q:3}, {w:5}]) ? I dont want to write own parser which should do more than separate parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best solution seemed to be:

in js: to make string from method's name you need to call, then add to string js parameters as one object with stringify, then send this string to WebView

in objC: get by my own method's name, then use [jsonkit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) to get complete dictionary with parameters (which can be arrays of dictionaries etc)